# How to get the FilterValue from the URL into calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, url

I have some link in my Sharepoint site, the URL link is included a filter-Value
Something like this:`http://www.test.com/test/pages/test.aspx#inplviewHash=filterValue=blabla.`

I want to fill some calculated column in "blabla".

How can I do that?

Comment: Is "blabla" fixed value i.e. number characters or fix text?

Comment: Hey, i have few filters. blabla, kuku, gogo. i want to fill calculated column in this filter value. thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this: 
 You will have an idea how to achieve this.   http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: viewmaster365 no longer exists; content is at: https://sharepoint-tools.github.io/formulas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  I am assuming that filterValue will remain unchanged.  It is extracting the values before 'filterValue' and replacing it with an empty string.

I initially thought it can be done with '=' but since you have two '=' example is using 'filterValue' to Find.

```
=REPLACE([URL],1,FIND("filterValue=",[URL])+11,"")
```